# gpg verify of GNU Emacs download fails - Did I do it correctly?

Tags: download, gnupg, gpg-signature

I have downloaded a GNU tar archive (`emacs-26.1.tar.xz`) and now want to verify it against its signature file. `gpg` returns with the `verify` option the following output:

```
    gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
    gpg: the signature could not be verified.
```

Obviously the download could not be verified. **But what does this mean? Is the tar archive probably corrupt? Or had I not imported the correct keys?**

---

Here is step-by-step what I did:

1. I downloaded the archive file and its `.sig` file:

   ```
   $ wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/emacs-26.1.tar.xz
   $ wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/emacs-26.1.tar.xz.sig
   ```
2. I downloaded the GNU keyring (the [Emacs download page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html) gave me the link):

   ```
   $ wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg
   ```
3. With `gpg` I imported the GNU keyring:

   ```
   $ gpg --import gnu-keyring.gpg
   ```

   Note that this returned:

   ```
   .
   .
   .
   gpg: Total number processed: 525
   gpg:               imported: 525  (RSA: 187)
   gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
   ```
4. Finally I verified the tar archive:

   ```
   gpg --verify emacs-26.1.tar.xz.sig emacs-26.1.tar.xz
   ```

   This then returned (as stated at the top):

   ```
   gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
   gpg: the signature could not be verified.
   Please remember that the signature file (.sig or .asc)
   should be the first file given on the command line.
   ```

So, is the tar archive corrupt or had I not imported the correct keys? If the latter is the case, what are the correct keys for this GNU download?